# HighCharts Organization Nodes Overlapping

Tags: css, highcharts, nodes, overlap

I have a HighCharts organization chart that loads data from our db so it can have a variable number of nodes. I've added

```
.highcharts-container { overflow: scroll !important; min-width: 100px; }
```

to my css so that the scrollbars appear and it seems to be growing as needed vertically. However, the nodes overlap horizontally for some reason. I've added

```
nodePadding: 15
```

to my js which seems to space them out vertically but doesn't help the horizontal issue. I feel like there should be an option or setting for this, but when I search on overlapping issues, all I get are label issues. Any ideas on how to get my nodes to space out? Thanks!
[image: my org chart, spaced vertically nicely but horizontally badly]

Here's a jsFiddle which has overlapping data like mine - https://jsfiddle.net/ubmzs5qf/

In case things get unconnected at some point, here's a function given to me by Sebastian here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=42435&p=149331 that handles resizing for the amount of data:

```
events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this,
      series = chart.series[0],
      newWidth = series.options.nodeWidth * series.nodeColumns[2].length;

    chart.update({
      chart: {
        width: newWidth
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I used this to set both the height and width but it's being overwritten by something, possibly a higher angular limit on dialog size. I think I need a way to space out the icons and make everything small since I can't just make the chart bigger.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle to my question

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by decreasing nodes width eg. `nodeWidth: 50`.

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d9cmt0oy/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.nodeWidth

---

**EDIT**

Another way is to decrease `dataLabels font size and set manually the height and offset of each larger node.

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8om5hc34/1/

Comment: That does make them not overlap, however now the nodes are so small you can't read what they say on them. I think my management wants the node titles visible and not overlapping, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I think there's no way around it - if you want a lot of data, it's going to be small. Your answer combined with Sebastian's load() function here is what I'm going to attempt to implement. Thanks! 
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=42435&p=149331